# Passing Variables to aspx page from code page behind to get variable path

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

### Web.Config

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=ReplaceKamToken\App_Data\BIAS_PASexport_DATA.accdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mi"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

### Default.aspx.vb

```
Public ReadOnly Property CustomConnectionString() As String
    Get
        Dim con As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim c As String = con.Replace("ReplaceKamToken", Server.MapPath("~"))
        Return c
    End Get
End Property
```

### Default.aspx

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString= "<%= CustomConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [PickList] FROM [T_BAS_PASexport]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I got above codes in relevant files.  I am keep getting the below error.
An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB 

I did try changing the Provider and other things as well but keep getting the errors like 
An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB 
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed

Keyword not supported: '<%'

All i need is to pass variables to my Default.aspx file from Default.aspx.vb file to get variable path for the connection string as i can not use Server.Mappath in my Web.Config file. Please can any one help me on this.

Comment: You could set it in the OnInit of the page "SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = "...". You might have to use binding <%# CustomConnectionString %> instead.

Comment: Please can you explain bit more in detail.  I tried putting line <%# CustomConnectionString %> as per you suggestion in above comment but still getting error.

Comment: Since it's runat="server" an instance of that control is created in the codebehind. In the page Init event, you have access to that control and can set the connection string there by doing: SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = CustomConnectionString